# Usable network speed increases when screen is locked, why?

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth, spyware

While diagnosing my slow network, I've noticed that [my connection speeds up whenever I lock my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3K55.png)

The peaks in the linked image correspond exactly to when my screen is locked (using Win+L), and the network usage is caused by a Steam download.

The download runs at 2 MByte/s (displayed inside Steam) when I'm logged in, but at 3 MByte/s when I've locked the screen using Win+L. The Steam download graph shows the same peaks as the task manager.

I have no idea what could cause this. The only semi-reasonable explanation I could come up with is that I could have screen recording spyware or something that streams my screen somewhere else, and somehow hides its used bandwidth from the task manager's network graph, but stops whenever I lock my screen so the bandwidth is free to be used by other programs.

Do you have any other ideas what this could be, or in case you do believe it to be malware, any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Comment: Did you try to scan your computer for malwares ? Also, you should install something like the ZoneAlarm firewall that will block all outbound connections aswell and ask for authorisation. You also can monitor your network using wireshark or the windows 'netstat -b' cmd call.